# messageParent working for desktop Word but not web Word

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

For my Word add-in, the login flow works great on desktop Word, but with web/browser/online Word, it breaks at the `messageParent` step.

Here is a summary of the process:

1. User clicks login from add-in pane and the add-in opens up a dialog with `displayDialogAsync` to `https://myapp.com/login`
2. User goes through the login process.
3. In the dialog, the user is redirected back to `https://myapp.com/login-done` (same domain we started with and the domain of the add-in)
4. The `login-done` page includes the Javascript below:

> ```
> (function () {
>   Office.onReady(function() {
>     $(document).ready(function () {
>       Office.context.ui.messageParent('done!');
>     });
>   });
> }());
> ```

5. The add-in panel Javascript finishes up:

> ```
> function login_finish() {
>   console.log('DONE!!!');
>   dialog.close();
>   location.reload();
> }
> ```

This last bit of Javascript never gets executed with browser Word though it does with desktop Word.  I don't see the `DONE!!!` message in the console.

No relevant errors are shown in the console of the dialog or the side panel.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?  This is with Chrome 87 and Mac OS X 10.15.7.

Answer (score 0):

I got access to a Windows 10 computer and tried the same code there.  It works on Windows 10 with both Edge and IE11.  Looks like there is a bug in Office.js relating to Chrome and/or Mac OS X.